# Am I calling to many jquery sessions?

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery and currently have placed the jquery UI tab - http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#mouseover on my page. Within a tab I have also placed a jquery table and it is working great. I am trying to place the FlexSlider photo slider within another tab and it is not working. It is causing my page to return everything within the tabs stacked on top of each other that has my layout all sorts of screwed up. Like I said I am new to jquery and each component that I use comes with a script and a link to place within the head section of my code. Am I calling jquery too many times and overloading/overriding jquery as I suspect? I am sure one call is sufficient and have tried just calling jquery using google api. 
currently I am calling jquery -1.8.3, jquery 1.9.2 ui, and  jquery min 1.6.2 via google.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We're unlikely to be able to help you without seeing more context. Could you post your actual code here and [describe what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Be sure also to check the [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Thanks!

Comment: You should use only one jQuery version; ideally the newest one. Just remove the references to the others.

Comment: I am sorry, I am trying to figure out this forum as I have never posted in it before. Which version of jquery should I call of those suggested? Is it possible that I need to change the width and height of the slider in the css file from flexslider to correct the problem?

Comment: I have commented out the call to google api, which corrects the layout put the slider is not appearing as it should.

Comment: I don't know how to put code in the message for the post to accept it. I will figure it out on my own, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery and jQuery-min are basically the same thing, except the latter has all the white space stripped out of it to make the file size smaller. You only need one of these. Probably at this point, you'll want to use whichever is the more recent version.

jQuery-ui is something else altogether, so you'll want to keep that one around if you're using UI methods.

As a reminder, make sure that jQuery is the first script you call in your header. And install Firebug or use the Chrome console to look for any errors in your loaded JavaScripts.

Once you've got all this done, then maybe you'll be better prepared to  describe your troubles in greater detail.